# Do :nth-of-type(n) "n" counters increment independently with others in the same CSS rule?

Tags: css, css3pie

Do the n counters increment independently of each other in :nth-of-type() CSS selectors?  For example, if I wanted label:checked:nth-of-type(3) to match its general sibling article:nth-of-type(3), should this technique work?  (It doesn't, but maybe I just want to be sure.)

```
label:checked:nth-of-type(n) ~ article:nth-of-type(n)
```

The idea is not to have to explicitly say :nth-of-type(1), :nth-of-type(2), and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately for you, the `n` counter is local to the `nth-of-type` where it is defined, so your technique won't work. You would have to do something like this:

```
label:checked:nth-of-type(1) ~ article:nth-of-type(1),
label:checked:nth-of-type(2) ~ article:nth-of-type(2),
label:checked:nth-of-type(3) ~ article:nth-of-type(3),
label:checked:nth-of-type(4) ~ article:nth-of-type(4),
label:checked:nth-of-type(5) ~ article:nth-of-type(5), ...
{
    /* definitions */
}
```

...which is a pain. I see where you are going with it, and it would be great to be able to use something like that!